# How can I set Content-Security-Policy Report-To header in Nginx +1.17?

Tags: nginx

According to [CSP MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to), report-to takes a JSON object, but I can't find a way to embed JSON in Nginx configuration.
I tried this code and all the variants I can think of, escaping the quotes, adding single quotes, etc.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy
    "default-src 'self';
    report-uri https://example.com/csp-report;
    report-to {"group":"csp-endpoint","max_age":10886400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://example.com/csp-reports"}]}";
```

Is it possible to embed JSON in add_header directive with or without additional Nginx modules?

Comment: Surround the entire expression with single quotes and use only double quotes inside. In that way there is no need to escape any quotes. For example: `'default-src "self"; ... csp-reports"}]}';`

Comment: @RichardSmith Unfortunately the keywords require single-quotes, as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#implementation_details

Comment: This also works: `'default-src \'self\'; ... csp-reports"}]}';`

Answer (score 5):

Answering my question. The cleanest approach I end up with is to have a separate Report-To header, taking JSON between single quote.

```
add_header Report-To '{"max_age":31536000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://example.com/csp-report"}]}';
```

Then the Content-Security-Policy header reference the report-to groupname, which is `default` by default.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy 
    "default-src 'self'; 
    report-uri https://example.com/csp-report;
    report-to default";
```